# Problem with classicthesis and small caps

Tags: fonts, small-caps, classicthesis

## Obtaining the example code

I tried compiling the `classicthesis` example documents, especially `classicthesis-book.tex`. Therefore I copied the directory to my home folder with

```
cp -R $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFDIST)/doc/latex/classicthesis ~/
```

Then I went to `~/classicthesis/Examples/` and adjusted `classicthesis-book.tex`, such that

```
%\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{../classicthesis} % ,manychapters
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis} % ,manychapters
```

because `classicthesis.sty` is not in the directory above. Then I compiled using

```
pdflatex classicthesis-book.tex
```

It completed without errors. I reran this some times to get the index updated.

## Problem

When executing the above work flow, there are no small caps in the TOC for the part numbers. Compare these two

#### Original

> [image]

#### Self compiled

> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in a strange behavior of `titlesec` that makes impossible to use `tocloft` commands for adjusting the appearance of the part entries in the TOC.

The following code in the preamble seems to fix the issue:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ttl@tocpart{%
  \def\ttl@a{\protect\numberline{\thepart}\@gobble{}}}
\makeatother
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{1.5em}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Could you please be so kind, as to add a short explanation of what your code does?

Comment: @HenriMenke To be honest, I don't really know what precisely the various incarnations of `\ttl@a` do in `titlesec`. I found this workaround (in a different context) and tried it with your problem. Probably @JavierBezos can explain it.

Comment: Do we really need `\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{1.5em}` here? I don't see a difference when I remove it.